# How to pass array values in protractor using CMD for params?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, protractor

I'm looking to pass a specific value of array using the params so that the scripts execute only for that specific country code. Below is the example of code:

```
var countryData = browser.params.country.countriestoExecute;
console.log("---"+countryData);
countryData.forEach(function(countryCode) {
    var dataFile = require("../../countries/" + countryCode + ".json");
```

I made the following changes on config file under params are:

```
params:{
      country:{
          countriestoExecute: require('../data/countries/countriesForReview.json')['Country'][0].countryIsocode.split(","),
      } 
  },
```

Whenever I'm running for every country using command in cmd as : `protractor conf.js` this it is working perfectly & taking value one by one from my JSON file.

But when I tried to provide only one value let as 'IN' from the params it's give error as following:

```
Error: TypeError: countryData.forEach is not a function
```

Although the console.log above printing countryData value as IN. Command used: `protractor conf.js --params.country.countriestoExecute=IN`

Below is the JSON file format:

```
{
  "Country": [
    {
      "countryIsocode": "IN,US"
    }
  ]
}
```

Any suggestion where I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You are passing the value for `countriestoExecute` as `IN` which is intern not an array.

Comment: so could you suggest how to proceed forward in this case. I tried quite a few combinations.